# Intellij IDEA database tool: Is it possible to remain sorting by column after reopening the "table view data" tab

Tags: intellij-idea

Suppose I sorted the table by one of its columns:

[image]

But then if I close this tab and open it again, the order will be lost, and I'll need to click on the column to sort it again.

With sorting by multiple columns things become even worse.

Is there any possibility to save the sorting preferences in IDEA? For example, SQLDeveloper has this option.

I'm using Intellij IDEA 2019.3.4 Ultimate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, please create feature request on [our tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/DBE)